# DOS CMD batch: Why does 'DIR *.*' list also directories?

Tags: cmd, dir

```
DIR *.*
```

I expect directories that don't have `.` in their names don't meet the `*.*` mask but they are listed. Why?

Comment: The link leads back to this page.

Comment: Sorry copy paste error here ;-) [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) should be the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

`*.*` means all files, all extensions, presumably that means extensionless too i.e. folders